# can the emphasis on "smallest" in the monotone class theorem be ignored in applications?

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

The monotone class theorem states that for any algebra of sets $\cal A$ one can construct the smallest monotone class generated by this class ${\cal M}(\cal A)$. This smallest monotone class is also the smallest sigma-algebra $\Sigma(\cal A)$ generated by $\cal A$, and ${\cal M}(\cal A)=\Sigma(\cal A)$.

However, I noticed that in applications of the theorem in various mathematical proofs I have studied authors ignore the fact that the monotone class should be the smallest.

For example, assume that the goal is to prove that a certain class of sets, e.g. $\cal B$, is a sigma-algebra. Authors just prove that this group of sets is a monotone class, and then by invoking the monotone class theorem, without showing that $\cal B$ is indeed the smallest monotone class, just conclude that this class has to be also a sigma-algebra.

Is it in general possible to ignore the "smallest" requirement when using the monotone class theorem, or are there circumstances one has to be aware of that make such use possible?

EDIT: The background to the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164919/help-needed-to-understand-a-theorem-from-measure-theory-approximation-by-really). The post discusses a theorem where the "smallest" requirement is being ignored.  It provides an example.

Comment: In your first sentence you use the term "the smallest monotone class generated by...".  This is redundant: do you mean "the smallest monotone class containing..."?  If so, this is equivalent to "the monotone class generated by...".  (I'm just trying to rule this out as a possible basis for your question.)

Comment: @zorank, I've noticed the same thing. Authors often show a set **is** a monotone class, and that the other hypothesis of the monotone class theorem are satisfied, but don't show that the monotone class they've chosen is the smallest such.

Comment: @Robert: Indeed, isn't that strange? To me it sounds strange, but I am not a mathematician. I guess that in the proofs we are discussing there is always an implicit assumption made that is obvious to professionals in the field.

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, "the smallest monotone class containing" is correct. But I believe that people do use "generated by" sometimes. (I am not 100% sure though, but I think it does not matter, assume the question is phrased with the "containing" version; please let me know if I am wrong thinking like this).